# installshield projects runtime error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, installshield, sql-scripts

I've created a project in installshiel program uses SQL Server 2008 and written in C#.

Everything works fine and scripts of database also works fine but I had error when trying to install program which is created by installshield

error is

> Error 27506. Error executing SQL script db_name.sql. Line 9
>   The CREATE DATABASE statement failed. The primary file must be at least 3
>   MB to accomodate a copy of the model database. (1803)

I tried to search in google but I couldn't find any results

please help

Comment: Well - the error really says it all - the database you're trying to create obviously has a file that is **too small** to hold a copy of the `model` database. Can you please check this, and/or post your SQL script that creates the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the installer.  It's doing exactly what it was told to do:  Execute a SQL script that was injected into it and report any errors that occur.

You didn't actually provide the contents of the SQL but basically you need to look at the [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) statement paying attention to the SIZE, MAXSIZE and FILEGROWTH arguments.